# React Router v6 Navigate to absolute path from subrouter

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Suppose we have this situation:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Master/>}/>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Auth/>}>
        <Route path="" element={<AuthInitiate/>}/>
        <Route path="callback" element={<AuthCallback/>}/>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

Suppose we currently are in `/login/callback`. Inside the `AuthCallback` component I use:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate("/")
```

The result is that i get redirected to `/login`, so I understand that the `"/"` refers to the relative subroute we are in (that is, `/login`). This is super useful in a lot of situations, but here I just to redirect with respect to the absolute path, so `"/"` should mean exactly `/` and not `/login`.

How should I do?

Be aware I'm referring to the new React Router v6.

EDIT: I had something else redirecting the route, the code instead works exactly as expected and `navigate("/")` from subroute indeed navigate to root level. There are no issues with navigation from subroutes, sorry.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe with the code you've shared. Check this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-navigate-to-absolute-path-from-subrouter-o0vxy?file=/src/App.js) demo that appears to navigate absolutely to `"/"` from `"/login/callback"`.

Comment: You're right I was wrong there were something else misbehaving in my router configuration, sorry about that.

Comment: Do you still have an issue? If so can you update your question to include the new details?

Comment: Updated the question with the details, it was a false problem, your codesandbox works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Even though OP's problem is already resolved, I think it may be worth leaving this answer here for future travelers:

Use a **leading slash** to navigate to an absolute path:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

// Absolute path:
navigate('/login/auth');

// Relative paths:
navigate('login');
navigate('login/auth');
navigate('../login');
```

Also noteworthy: In React Router v6 [trailing slashes are ignored](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-route-path-patterns).

Answer (score 1):

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

It states that

if you want relative path use

```js
const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('users')
```

if not then use

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/dashboard/users')
```